# Compute a recursive algorithm in parallel using Task

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, parallel-processing, task

how do I convert this sequential recursive algorithm into a parallel recursive algorithm using tasks?

```
public static List<int> s = new List<int>(); // random integers, array size is n
public static List<int> p = new List<int>(); // random integers, array size is n
public static int n = 100;
public static int w = 10;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    G1(n, w)
}

private static int G1(int k, int r)
{
    if (k == 0 || r == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (s[k - 1] > r)
    {
        return G1(k - 1, r);
    }

    return Math.Max(G1(k - 1, r), p[k - 1] + G1(k - 1, r - s[k - 1]));
}
```

I have an example, but it's too confusing, it has no explanations and is not as complex as in my case.

```
class CustomData
{
    public int TNum;
    public int TResult;
}

static int F1(int n)
{
    if (n > 1) return F1(n - 1) + F1(n - 2);
    else return 1;
}

static int F2(int n)
{
    int fibnum = 0;
    if (n < 6) fibnum = F1(n);
    else
    {
    //fibnum = F1(n - 3) + 3 * F1(n - 4) + 3 * F1(n - 5) + F1(n - 6);
    int countCPU = 4;
    Task[] tasks = new Task[countCPU];
    for (var j = 0; j < countCPU; j++)
    tasks[j] = Task.Factory.StartNew(
    (Object pp) =>
    {
        var data = pp as CustomData; if (data == null) return;
        data.TResult = F1(n - data.TNum - 3);
    },
    new CustomData() {TNum = j });
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    fibnum = (tasks[0].AsyncState as CustomData).TResult + 3 * (tasks[1].AsyncState as CustomData).TResult + 3 * (tasks[2].AsyncState as CustomData).TResult + (tasks[3].AsyncState as CustomData).TResult;
    }
    return fibnum;
}
```

Comment: What is p and s in the Method?

Comment: Those are arrays of randomly generated integers, array size is k (original)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually, note that the parallelization is only done in the "first iteration" - it launches four separate non-trivial tasks, so for large enough `n`, you'll get pretty close to perfect efficiency. Reproducing the same thing for the second excercise will require the same kind of mathematical insight (allowing the near-equal partitioning of workloads). But if `G1(k - 1, r)` has similar workload to `G1(k - 1, r - s[k - 1])`, the most trivial parallelization would give at least two threads some work to do.

Comment: Check [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672543/parallel-fibonacci-number-calculator). Fibonacci can't be parallelized and this code is an example of what not to do with tasks - creating tasks by hand, blocking on them, using a hard-coded number of cores.

Comment: @Luaan I realized this after trying to decipher the code. Using the Parallel.ForEach overload that uses local state would be a lot simpler and possibly faster

Answer (score 1):

The overhead from parallelization is rather high for a simple task like this, so you definitely don't want to parallelize every iteration naïvely. However, the sample task is rather complicated in not only changing the recursive function to a (somewhat) parallelized recursive function, but finding extra parallelization options to get four independent workers. It's also further complicated by using outdated multi-threading constructs. Consider a simpler example:

```
static int F2(int n)
{
  if (n <= 1) return 1;

  var a = Task.Run(() => F1(n - 1));
  var b = Task.Run(() => F1(n - 2));

  return a.Result + b.Result;
}
```

We split the original workload (rather trivially) into two branches. Since both branches have roughly similar amount of workload, this allows us to efficiently use two threads. Note that this is *extremely stupid* - you're computing the same thing twice, and using two threads to do the workload that a single thread could do just as well (even without a deeper understanding of recursive functions like the Fibonacci sequence) just by caching results for a given `n`.

But I'll assume that the point of the excercise is to show how you can parallelize tasks *regardless* of how parallelizable those tasks actually are (i.e. you're *expected* to be stupid and naïve). How did we get from the two-threaded version to the four-threaded version? By skipping the first iteration, and starting on the second right away. This gives you *four* branches, instead of the original two.

Let's assume you have `n > 6` (in the sample, `F1` is used otherwise as a special case). The first iteration of F1 works out roughly to:

```
return F1(n - 1) + F1(n - 2);
```

But we want to merge this with the second iterations, to allow four-way parallelization. This is as simple as substituting `F1(n)` for `F1(n - 1) + F1(n - 2)`:

```
return F1((n - 1) - 1) + F1((n - 1) - 2) + F1((n - 2) - 1) + F1((n - 2) - 2);
```

Which can be simplified to

```
return F1(n - 2) + F1(n - 3) + F1(n - 3) + F1(n - 4);
```

and further to

```
return F1(n - 2) + 2 * F1(n - 3) + F1(n - 4);
```

Oops! We lost one of the branches. So we actually need *another* substitution:

```
return 
  F1((n - 2) - 1) + F1((n - 2) - 2)
  + 2 * (F1((n - 3) - 1) + F1((n - 3) - 2))
  + F1((n - 4) - 1) + F1((n - 4) - 2);
```

Which works out to...

```
return
 F1(n - 3) + F1(n - 4)
 + 2 * F1(n - 4) + 2 * F1(n - 5)
 + F1(n - 5) + F1(n - 6);
```

Which finally gets us to our four branches:

```
return
 F1(n - 3) + 3 * F1(n - 4) + 3 * F1(n - 5) + F1(n - 6);
```

Each of those branches can naïvely be run in parallel, and you get a good use of all four threads.

You can now hopefully apply the same reasoning to `G1` and get four-way parallelization of that particular recursive function :)

Comment: This makes it more clear for me, but I don't understand how to merge G1(k - 1, r) with other iterations. And I'm completely lost at Math.Max, how do I substitute that?

Comment: I could probably split the Math.Max parameters into two branches and that help me parallelize the algorithm with at least two threads. But I still don't know how to split G1(k - 1, r) into different tasks.

`private static int G2(int k, int r)
  {
   if (k == 0 || r == 0) return 0;

   if (s[k - 1] > r)
   {
    return G1(k - 1, r);
   }

   Task<int> max1 = Task.Run(() => G1(k - 1, r));
   Task<int> max2 = Task.Run(() => p[k - 1] + G1(k - 1, r - s[k - 1]));

   return Math.Max(max1.Result, max2.Result);
  }`

Comment: @PetroCepura You substitute the function "call" with the "body" of the function; it doesn't matter what the operator that acts on the results is. The substitution works exactly the same for `Max(a, b)` as for `Plus(a, b)` - you're substituting `G1` in `a` and `b`, what happens around that doesn't matter.

Comment: @PetroCepura Try to follow through the reasoning on the `F1` example; the exact same logic applies to `G1`. I'm afraid I can't give you any more hints without giving away the answer, which would be counter-productive :)

Comment: `return G1(k - 1, r)`
`return G1((k - 1) - 1, r) + G1((k - 2) - 1, r)`

Answer (score 0):

@Luaan this is my solution, using two threads. I don't know if it's alright, but the results of sequential and parallel algorithms match, however there's extremely little decrease in time, perhaps more threads need to be used?

```
private static int G2(int k, int r)
{
    if (k == 0 || r == 0) return 0;

    if (s[k - 1] > r) // this part gives the wrong results :(
    {
        Task<int> task1 = Task.Run(() => G1(k - 2, r));
        Task<int> task2 = Task.Run(() => G1(k - 3, r));
        return task1.Result + task2.Result;
    }

    Task<int> max1 = Task.Run(() => G1(k - 1, r));
    Task<int> max2 = Task.Run(() => p[k - 1] + G1(k - 1, r - s[k - 1]));

    return Math.Max(max1.Result, max2.Result);
}
```

if (s[k - 1] > r) block gives the wrong results :(

Comment: The `Math.Max` part is right, but the `if (s[k - 1] > r)` isn't - you need to do the same thing as with the max, except that the arguments is now `k - 1` instead of `k`. As for performance, that depends entirely on what values are allowed for `s` - if they are any integers, some of the branches will be significantly preferred over the others. If you can't do the analytics in your head, try building up statistics about which branches are more likely to be executed. To get decent parallelization, you need the workloads to be spread evenly. It may also be that you're memory-bound, rather than CPU

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how to split a function into two functions that could be used as two processes.

Comment: You already did that once - with the `max1` and `max2` :) But it seems like you don't quite understand how, otherwise you wouldn't make the mistake in the `s[k - 1] > r` block. Where did you get the `G1(k - 2, r)` and `G1(k - 3, r)`? Certainly not the same way as the other two branches later. Look again at my explanation of the thinking in the `F1` case - the first iteration simply splits the two branches already in the function, but to get to the four-way parallelism, you need to substitute the `F1` calls with the *code* of `F1`. I suspect this is the core of the excercise.