# Split recursive function into two or more processes

Tags: c#, function, math, recursion, parallel-processing

How do I split G1(k - 1, r) into two or more processes? For example, G1(k - 1, r) = G1(x1, x2) + G1(x3, x4). Below there's the original recursive algorithm.

```
 private static int G1(int k, int r)
 {
    if (k == 0 || r == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (s[k - 1] > r)
    {
        return G1(k - 1, r);
    }

    return Math.Max(G1(k - 1, r), p[k - 1] + G1(k - 1, r - s[k - 1]));
 }
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
private static int G2(int k, int r)
{
    if (k == 0 || r == 0) return 0;

    if (s[k - 1] > r) // this part gives the wrong results :(
    {
        Task<int> task1 = Task.Run(() => G1(k - 2, r));
        Task<int> task2 = Task.Run(() => G1(k - 3, r));
        return task1.Result + task2.Result;
    }

    Task<int> max1 = Task.Run(() => G1(k - 1, r));
    Task<int> max2 = Task.Run(() => p[k - 1] + G1(k - 1, r - s[k - 1]));

    return Math.Max(max1.Result, max2.Result);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "process" in this case? A separate thread? A new OS-level process? Something else?

Comment: I just need to split G1(k - 1, r) into two functions so I can run them in two different processes combining their results in the end. I need to parallelize it.

Comment: Why? What is `G1` computing? What are the `p` and `s` arrays for?

Comment: Are you trying to ask how do you parallelize the computation to take advantage of multiple threads? If so, looking into `Task`s and the associated TPL library

Comment: Updated, the code block `if (s[k - 1] > r)` in G2 gives me the wrong result as I failed to properly split the G1(k - 1, r) function into two functions.

Comment: Of course that gives you the wrong result. You're adding things together in G2 when G1 never did anything like that. There's a problem you're trying to solve. What is that problem?

Comment: How do I split `G1(k - 1, r)` into two functions so I can use them in two processes?

Comment: No, that's a solution to your perceived problem. Why are you trying to do this? What is the fundamental thing you're trying to achieve? What does G1 compute?

Comment: I'm trying to split it into two processes, in the end their results must be combined to get the final result.

Comment: You've already asked this same question earlier today: [Compute a recursive algorithm in parallel using Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44135281/compute-a-recursive-algorithm-in-parallel-using-task)

Comment: I didn't get the answer I need there.

Comment: You need to wait for one instead of spamming Stack Overflow. More importantly, you need to be much clearer about your question because it doesn't seem like anyone understands the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I told you already... Need to split G1(k - 1, r) into two functions G1(x, x,) and G1(x, x,), so their combined result is the result of G1(k - 1, r)

Comment: And I told you, to answer that we need to know what G1 is computing, and why you want to do this.

Comment: I don't know, it may be the Knapsack problem... That's irrelevant anyway.

Comment: You're coming on a website to ask experts for help. The experts say they need some extra information to help you. You say, that's irrelevant. If you're the expert on what is and isn't relevant, why are you here asking for help?

Comment: Like others said, you need to clarify what you're asking as many of us are unclear.  For example, the statement _"Need to split G1(k - 1, r) into two functions G1(x, x,) and G1(x, x,)"_ is very unclear - what does it mean to split it here into two identical things that not clear what is meant by them?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're going for parallelization of computation, and not splitting in separate OS processes.  You can use `Task` and TPL for the purpose:

```
private static async Task<int> G1(int k, int r)
 {
    if (k == 0 || r == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (s[k - 1] > r)
    {
        return await G1(k - 1, r);
    }

    var taskA = G1(k - 1, r);
    var taskB = G1(k - 1, r - s[k - 1]);

    await Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB);

    return Math.Max(taskA.Result, p[k - 1] + taskB.Result);
 }
```

Since the purpose of the algorithm here is not clear, the above assumes the computation itself is correct.  It just answers parallelization question, not correctness of the result, or possibility of needing to synchronize access to shared state.

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB);` why is this needed if the results of taskA and taskB are being used after the await line, the processes will be awaited anyway as their results are required.

Comment: Also, `return await G1(k - 1, r);` is not what I am looking for, I need it to be split into two processes without the need of using await.

Comment: Because `.Result` is a blocking call that will prevent the worker thread from doing something else while waiting for child task to complete.  Awaiting first allows for better concurrency.  Once awaited, then `.Result` is a safe call that will not cause blocking because result is readily available.

Comment: Re: `return await G1(k - 1, r);` not being what you're looking for - as I state at the end of my answer, I'm simply answering how to parallelize computing - not accuracy of algorithm.  Your original code in your question has `return G1(k - 1, r);` and because I changed `G1` from returning `int` to returning `Task<int>`, the `await` is needed there.